# CSS Flexbox - How to mobile responsive?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How would I make this section mobile responsive? I've designed it in a figma and copy and pasted the CSS that figma produced. Can flexbox alone make the text and image stack ontop of each as the screen size shrinks. Or would I just design the layout for each size screen in figma and then use media queries to call up the right css layout? Or is there any other way that's better to do this?

```css
/* Global Settings */
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: 0;
}

li,
a {
 font-size: 0.75rem;
 font-family: "Roboto";
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #303133;
 text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 0.75rem;
 font-family: "Roboto";
}

button {
 width: 176px;
 height: 47px;
 background: #6442ff;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Roboto";
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 18px;
 align-items: center;
 border: none;
}

.section2-h1 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 582px;
 height: 99px;
 left: 160px;
 top: 1645px;

 font-family: Roboto;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 50px;
 line-height: 59px;

 color: #303133;
}

.section2-p {
 position: absolute;
 width: 537px;
 height: 163px;
 left: 158px;
 top: 1765px;

 font-family: Roboto;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 25px;

 /* or 167% */
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;

 color: #777777;
}

.section2-img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 528px;
 height: 402px;
 left: 738px;
 top: 1626px;
}
.section2-button {
 position: absolute;
 width: 176px;
 height: 47px;
 left: 161px;
 top: 1962px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Web Design and Web Development">
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="section2">
    <header class="section2-head">
        <h1 class="section2-h1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame. 
        </h1>
        <p class="section2-p">Morbi sit amet varius nunc, blandit vulputate mi. Nulla a lobortis magna. Ut bibendum, augue quis lacinia tempus, justo ligula tincidunt ligula, eu bibendum ante libero imperdiet magna. Mauris vel consectetur arcu. Pellentesque risus tortor, lacinia nec dictum a, sagittis quis turpis. Aliquam dolor ante, rhoncus nec congue at, dictum vitae eros. Integer nec viverra leo. Curabitur blandit pretium rhoncus. In ut egestas elit</p>
        <img src="img/hello.jpg" alt="" class="section2-img">
        <button class="section2-button">READ MORE</button>
    </header>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To answer your question: yes flexbox alone can make the text and picture stack as the screen shrinks. Go through any of the numerous free tutorials online. I've never used Figma but damn that is some ugly HTML/CSS.

Comment: I'm new to all of this but it didn't seem right to me either. All the styles for H tags and P tags should just be written once in a global setting without each section heading and paragraph needing its own class such as "section2-p" right? As for the CSS can you explain what you see wrong with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word of advice, I would recommend that you learn how to write your own CSS rather than using the CSS produced by Figma. The CSS code produced by Figma uses absolute positioning to position your HTML elements which would work on one screen size, but the website would not be responsive as it won't work well on any other screen size. To make your website responsive, you should use things like margin and padding to position your code. You can use the Figma code as more of a starting point.

To answer your question, yes flexbox can be used to make the text stack on top of each other. This can be done by changing it from `display: flex;` to `display: block;` on smaller screen sizes using a media query. I would advise against using media queries to change the CSS for each screen size using the Figma CSS as you would have to do that for a lot of screen sizes. You should just have that one breakpoint to stack the items at a thin breakpoint.

Below is a code snippet of a suggestion on how to change the Figma CSS code to something more responsive:

```css
/* Global Settings */
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: 0;
}

li,
a {
 font-size: 0.75rem;
 font-family: "Roboto";
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #303133;
 text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 0.75rem;
 font-family: "Roboto";
}

button {
 width: 176px;
 height: 47px;
 background: #6442ff;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Roboto";
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 18px;
 align-items: center;
 border: none;
}

.section2-head {
 margin: 160px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-start;
}

.section2-text {
 max-width: 537px;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

.section2-h1 {
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 50px;
 line-height: 59px;

 margin-bottom: 10px;

 color: #303133;
}

.section2-p {
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 25px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 margin-bottom: 40px;

 color: #777777;
}

.section2-img {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 528px;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
 .section2-head {
  margin: 80px;
  display: block;
 }

 .section2-text {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-right: 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Web Design and Web Development">
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="section2">
    <header class="section2-head">
  <div class="section2-text">
   <h1 class="section2-h1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame. 
   </h1>
   <p class="section2-p">Morbi sit amet varius nunc, blandit vulputate mi. Nulla a lobortis magna. Ut bibendum, augue quis lacinia tempus, justo ligula tincidunt ligula, eu bibendum ante libero imperdiet magna. Mauris vel consectetur arcu. Pellentesque risus tortor, lacinia nec dictum a, sagittis quis turpis. Aliquam dolor ante, rhoncus nec congue at, dictum vitae eros. Integer nec viverra leo. Curabitur blandit pretium rhoncus. In ut egestas elit</p>
   <button class="section2-button">READ MORE</button>
  </div>
        <img src="img/hello.jpg" alt="" class="section2-img">
    </header>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would I position the button?  I want each section to have a height of 503px and split into 2 columns with the button 20px off the bottom. So would I set #section2 to have a height off 503px and then align the button left with button padding of 20px? I'm trying to replicate the sections on this site https://getkev.co.uk/

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean by your question. If you mean you want a 20px gap between the bottom of the button and bottom of the section, then you can either give the button a `margin-bottom: 20px;` or you can give the div containing the text and the button a `padding: 20px`. I would not recommend having a fixed height for your section as the height should depend on the lines of text. If you want to learn how to replicate the site, you can try to refer to the CSS using the browser developer tools.